# JQuery val() only true when 2 characters entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my input field  `<input type="number" id="warenAnzahl" class="lSInputs warenForm" name="warenanzahl" placeholder="Anzahl">`

and I'm trying to find out if this input field has a value. So I do

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {

    if($('#warenAnzahl').val()) {

        console.log("works")
    }
});
```

And it works when I enter at least two numbers. But it still returns false when the value is 1 character long.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for a wrong id, you ask for warenInput but it is warenAnzahl. In addition you should check for a on change event not a simple "if" since the if condition is only checked once when the page is loaded. Simply enter a number and press enter.

```js
$('#warenAnzahl').on('change', function(){
   console.log("works")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="warenAnzahl" class="lSInputs warenForm" name="warenanzahl" placeholder="Anzahl">
```

Comment: Thanks, but the wrong id was a mistake when formulating this question. I edited the whole question to clarify everything.

Comment: @MyNameisKev did you run my snippet? it works just like you wanted. If you have any further questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but do I need 2 eventListeners? I mean, I already check for a keypress. I need to know if the input is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you use wrong ID, you try to get `val()` of input which have ID is `warenInput` however in your example the ID of your input is `warenAnzahl`.

I hope this will help you to solve your problem :

```js
// Check Value by input event
$('#warenAnzahl').on('input', function() {
  console.log('Input value was changed');
  if ($(this).val()) {
    console.log('Value is not empty :', $(this).val());
  } else {
    console.log('Value is empty');
  }
});

// Check Value anywhere
$('#checkVal').click(function() {
  console.log('Check Value');
  let value = $('#warenAnzahl').val();
  if (value) {
    console.log('Value is not empty :', value);
  } else {
    console.log('Value is empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="warenAnzahl" class="lSInputs warenForm" name="warenanzahl" placeholder="Anzahl">
<button id="checkVal">Check Value</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I cant use change, because it should work without pressing enter. And the thing with the wrong Id was just wrong in this code snippet. Are there any other ways?

Comment: You can use `input` event which is call at each key entered :
`$('#warenAnzahl').on('input', function() {});`